# Pass an option from a class to another

Tags: class-options

I try to pass the `handout` option from my class to beamerclass. This method works. I tried with `\PassOptionsToClass` but it is not clear for me.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{beamer-nk}[2017/10/16 Beamer version nk, V4.1]

\newif\ifHandout
\Handoutfalse

\DeclareOption{handout}{\Handouttrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax

% classe de base
\ifHandout
\ExecuteOptions{handout}
\LoadClass[handout,xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfont,french]{beamer}
\else
\LoadClass[xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfont,french]{beamer}
\fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `\PassOptionsToClass{<option>}{<class>}` does is pass its first argument as an option to the class specified by its second argument. Since `\DeclareOption{<option>}{<code>}` causes `<code>` to be executed whenever `<option>` is passed as an option, you can use `\PassOptionsToClass` here to pass on an option.

The following would work for you:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{beamer-nk}[2017/10/16 Beamer version nk, V4.1]

\DeclareOption{handout}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}} 
%% N.B., you could replace "\CurrentOption" by "handout" in the line above.

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfont,french]{beamer}
```

If you also want to pass on other options to beamer you probably want the starred form, `\DeclareOption*`, which handles all unknown options (i.e., the ones you haven't declared).

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{beamer-nk}[2017/10/16 Beamer version nk, V4.1]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfont,french]{beamer}
```

Comment: isn't `\DeclareOption*{\ClassWarning{myclass}{Unknown option '\CurrentOption'}}` safer ?

Comment: There isn't really any harm in passing on unknown options: if beamer doesn't like an option, it'll produce its own error/warning. And if you some day decide that you want to pass another option to beamer you won't have to rewrite your wrapper class.

(Also: options to `\documentclass` aren't just passed to the class you are loading, but also to packages that can handle them regardless of whether the option is used by the class in question. A useful application of this is the draft option, which is used by many packages.)